# Проблема с pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Делал код по видео уроку. Проблема заключается в том, что при прыжке, медленно падает + проваливается сквозь пол.

**Код:**

```
import pygame 

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 400))

x = 100 
y = 300
wight = 60
height = 80 
speed = 7
jump = False
run = True
jumpCount = 10




while run:
    pygame.time.delay(10)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False


    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 5:
        x -= speed
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 635:
        x += speed
    if not(jump):
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            jump = True
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            if jumpCount < 0:
                y += (jumpCount ** 2) /4
            else:
                y -= (jumpCount ** 2) /2
                jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            jump = False
            jumpCount = 10
    window.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (0, 0, 255), (x, y, wight, height))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Я бы вам очень порекомендовал данный сайт(на нем очень подробно описывается информация) : https://proproprogs.ru/modules/klass-rect-ego-rol-svoystva-i-metody

Comment: Также советую посмотреть приложенное там видео

Comment: Там также есть пример-код, который реализует ваше требование.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Давайте посмотрим на этот кусочек кода

```
if jumpCount >= -10:
    if jumpCount < 0:
        y += (jumpCount ** 2) /4
    else:
        y -= (jumpCount ** 2) /2
        jumpCount -= 1
else:
    jump = False
    jumpCount = 10
```

очевидно, что jumpCount должен менятся от 10 до -10. При этом 10 и -10 соответствует положению "на земле", а 0 - самая "верхня точка". Также здесь используется то, что скорость меняется по квадрату, что бы обеспечить "реализм" (курс школьной физики за 7-8 класс и интегральное исчисление за 10-11).

Но проблема в том, что jumpCount меняется только на фазе "вверх", а на фазе "вниз" - нет. И переменная jumpCount остается -1 и шаг "падения остается 1/4. И условие "выходя с прыжка" не выполняется - поэтому и проваливаемся.

Фикс очень простой - просто убрать 4 пробела

```
if jumpCount >= -10:
    if jumpCount < 0:
        y += (jumpCount ** 2) /4
    else:
        y -= (jumpCount ** 2) /2
    jumpCount -= 1 # вот здесь!
else:
    jump = False
    jumpCount = 10
```

Но даже после этого оно падает "не до конца". Почему? да все просто - там есть два разных делителя - 4 и 2. Самое простое - сделать их одинаковыми.

Но что, если хочется "сохранить эффект замедления при приземлении"? тут есть разные способы, я придумал такой. Так как падение у нас более длинное, то вместо -10 нужно написать чуточку больше. -13 много, проваливается, -12 - чуть не добирает. Но это можно поправить отдельной строкой, даже будет лучше

```
if jumpCount >= -12:
    if jumpCount < 0:
        y += (jumpCount ** 2) /4
    else:
        y -= (jumpCount ** 2) /2
    jumpCount -= 1
else:
    jump = False
    jumpCount = 10
    y = 300 # вот так:)
```

и теперь оно прыгает как зайчик:)